# Angular reusable router change observer

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using router change observer in different components. I would like to have it reusable so I dont need to include this code into every component that needs it. How could I achive this?

```
changeObserver = null;

constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.changeObserver = router.events.pipe(
          filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)  
          ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
            if(event instanceof NavigationEnd)
              // change of url
              //--
              // call some component functions - different for each component
              //--
          });
       }

ngOnDestroy()
{
  this.changeObserver.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate Service class to handle this small piece of code and will give you option of callback which will handles the async operations.

### NavigationService

```
@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {

  private changeObserver;

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

  execute(callback) {
    this.changeObserver = router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd)
              callback();
        });
  }

}
```

### In Component

```
constructor(private NavigationService: navigationService) {

        this.navigationService.execute(()=>{
             //your code goes here.
        });
       }
```

> Note : The code is written in stackoverflow editor directly so there could be some typo and syntactical error. Please correct yourself.

Comment: Looks good, but how do I unsubscribe after I leave this component and want same functionality on the other? With this setup callbacks are adding to each other.

Comment: Already solved it. Removed from app.module providers and added into component providers. Also added `ngOnDestroy() { ...unsubscribe(); }` into service. Service singleton was the problem. Is there any problem with solution like this?

Comment: That is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an abstract class which implements what you want and extend the ones you want to have that routing implementation.

```
abstract class BaseComponent {
    observer;

    constructor() {
        this.observer = [1, 2, 3].forEach(number => {
            this.do(number);
        });
    }

    onDestroy() {
        // this.observer.unsubscribe();
    }

    abstract do(number);
}
```

And implement:

```
class Component extends BaseComponent {
    do(number) {
        console.log(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but since I'm already extending component with other class, I went with service solution.